# How to validate input using js and store the input in db

Tags: javascript, python

Javascript code:

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function validate()
        {
            var FirstName = document.getElementById('FN').value;
            var LastName  = document.getElementById('LN').value;
            var Username  = document.getElementById('userName').value;
            var Email     = document.getElementById('emailId').value;
            var Password  = document.getElementById('passWord').value;

            if (FirstName == "")
            {
                alert("Please Enter First Name");
                return false;
            }
            if (LastName == "")
            {
                alert("Please Enter Last Name");
                return false;
            }
            if (Username == "")
            {
                alert("Username Should Not Contain Spaces");
                return false;
            }
            if (Email == "")
            {
                alert("Please Enter Email");
                return false;
            }
            if (Password == "")
            {
                alert("Password Should Not Contain Spaces");
                return false;
            }
            var emailPat = /^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/;
            var EmailmatchArray = Email.match(emailPat);
            if (EmailmatchArray == null)
            {
                alert("Your Email Address Seems Incorrect. Please Try Again.");
                return false;
            }
            if(FirstName!== "" && LastName!=="" && Username!=="" && Email!=="" && Password!=="")
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
</script>
      <form action="Registration" method="get">
FirstName   :     <input type="text"     id="FN"       name="FN"><br>
LastName    :     <input type="text"     id="LN"       name="LN"><br>
UserName    :     <input type="text"     id="userName" name="userName"><br>
Password    :     <input type="password" id="passWord" name="passWord"><br>
Email       :     <input type="text"     id="emailId"  name="emailId"><br>
<input type="Submit" onclick="validate()">
```

Python code:

```
            class Registration(View):
           def get(self, request,msg):
            user_name = request.GET['userName']
            Firstname = request.GET['FN']
            Lastname = request.GET['LN']
            pass_word = request.GET['passWord']
            email_id = request.GET['emailId']
            db_results = usersCollection.find({"userName": user_name})
            print db_results
            print db_results.count()
            print user_name
            print dumps(db_results)
            if db_results.count() == 0:
                    token = binascii.b2a_hex(os.urandom(25))
                    #encrypting password...
                    encrypted_password = pwd_context.encrypt(pass_word)
                    database_key = usersCollection.insert(
                        {"Firstname":Firstname, "Lastname":Lastname, "userName": user_name, "passWord": encrypted_password, "emailId": email_id, "token": token,
                         "status": 0, "isSuperUser": "No", "forgotPasswordToken": '',
                         "createdOn": datetime.datetime.now()})
            if database_key != '':
                    return_output = {'message': 'Signup completed successfully! ', 'status': 'success'}
                    return HttpResponse(dumps(return_output))
```

HI friends I want to validate the input using javascript and if all the fields are correct then i want to store them in db I have put the code to do that but when i submit the form without input am getting only one alert message and then after closing the alert am getting a message written in python code and the empty input is stored in db please help where am i doing wrong.........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what is happening is that your form is getting submitted anyway, irrespective of the  return value of the function.

So instead of calling the validate() function on click, call in onsubmit. like this-

```
<form action="Registration" method="get" onsubmit="return validate();">
```

and remove the onclick event.
When false is returned from validate(), the form will not be sent.